# Measure only positive changes in Prometheus's increase() function

Tags: prometheus, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using Prometheus to scrape AWS cloudwatch metrics and send alerts when certain SQS queues spike up in their # of messages. Say my queue depth graph looks like this: [image: Image of a line graph trending downwards.]

I'd want an alarm when it spikes only *upward*. Currently, I'm using the expression `increase(QueueDepthMetric[10m])`, where `QueueDepthMetric` is the variable represented in the visual above. I anticipated that this would only show spikes where the metric increases, but it instead shows spikes where the metric's **slope** increases: [image: Another line graph, showing the derivative values of the first graph.]

This causes the alarm threshold to be reached on any spike, both positive and negative. After browsing the ["Query Functions" page](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase) of the Prometheus documentation, I was unable to find the function that I'm looking for.

**Is there a metric function or formula in Prometheus that will only show increases in a metric, rather than any net change?**

Note that I'm not looking to determine a raw Queue Depth threshold; rather, I'm looking to determine when the number increases dramatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`increase` is for counters, and queue depth is a gauge. Those spikes are actually where the value decreased as they were treated as counter resets.

What you want is `deriv` which will give you the slope over the given time period based on a simple linear regression.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try this. I read that `increase` ignores counter resets, but maybe I misinterpreted that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `increase` doesn't ignore counter resets, it handles then. You might be thinking of `nonNegativeDerivative` from Graphite and friends.